# Video tag - streaming video, how do i know if it's displaying anything?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm building a web service that uses video streams. I want to take a snapshot whenever a new stream comes, but the problem is that the stream is all black while the data loads. How can I know if my stream is ready for the snapshot, that is, how do I know if the video element is displaying anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that audio and video tag has something called readyState.

readyState === 4 means that it has enough data available to start playing.

This site really helped me figure it out.
http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html